# Record a list of installed packages and configurations before installing a higher version of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, package-management, configuration

I now have 12.04 installed, and would like to install 14.04.

1. Is it recommended to create a list of **installed packages**, so that I
   can install them back after installing 14.04?

   What about those packages installed with no record in `dpkg`, such as those installed by `configure`, `make` and `make install` from source?

   If yes, how?
2. Is it also recommended to save the **configurations** of 12.04 and
   installed packages somewhere, so that I can make the same
   configurations after installing 14.04?

   If yes, how to do that (efficiently)?

Thanks.

Comment: there's a package called apt-clone that is supposed to save your package states -- a command  close to 'dpkg -l "*" | grep ^ii' will show you all your installed packages.  As for the make-installed .. kinda on your own!

Comment: tho, I'd suggest installing 14, and your most commonly used .. then reinstalling packages as you need them. =/